# symfony2 creating json from object

Tags: php, json, symfony

Hi I am trying to generate json as response using symfony2.

Here is my code.

```
/**
 * @Route("/viewComments/{taskId}")
 *
 */
public function viewCommentsAction($taskId)
{
    $commentsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Comments")
                                        ->findBy(array("task" => $taskId));
    if (!$commentsList) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException("non comments to show");
    }
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $json = $serializer->serialize(
                                $commentsList,
                                'json', array('groups' => array('group1'))
    );
    return new Response($json);

}
```

unfortunately I am getting response:

```
[[],[],[],[]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `serializer` activated in your `app/config/config.yml`?

Comment: The serialize component works on objects.  I'm guessing that you are passing in an array of objects.  You will need a bit more code to serialize each individual object into arrays, combine the arrays into one big array then use the JsonResponse object.

Comment: hi scoolnico the serializer is actived app/config/config.yml  serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }

Comment: Hi Cerad, I var_dump($commentsList); and I see one array containing 4 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, creates a file: CommentRepository

```
class CommentRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findCommentsList($id)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('YOUR QUERY HERE');
        ...

        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

as you can see, I return an Array and now you can see values on the response.
Later, changes the next line in your Action Controller:

```
...
$commentsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Comments")
                                        ->findCommentsList($taskId));
...
```

**Note:** You should call your entities in singular